# Find the area between the curve $y = \cos x$ between the points $x = 0$ and $x = \pi$

Tags: integration

Find the area between the curve $y = \cos x$ between the points $x = 0$ and $x = \pi$.

$\int_0^{\pi} \cos x$ $ dx$

$[sin x]^{\pi}_0$

This does not make sense because both $\sin x = 0$ and $\sin \pi = 0$

Comment: It make sense, and the area is nulle ! (make a draw !)

Comment: this is integration and the integral of $\cos$ is $\sin$.

Answer (score 1):

You did it wrong. $\int_0^{\pi} \cos x dx$ is just the *definite integral* of $\cos x$ from $0$ to $\pi$, not the *area*. What you want to find is
$$
\int_0^{\pi}|\cos x| dx.
$$

---

**Edit:** Ok, I will add some description. See the picture below:
[image]

The orange curve is the graph of $y=|\cos x|$, and the green curve is the graph of $y=\cos x$. If you just calculate $\int_0^{\pi}\cos x dx$, then you compute the area from $0$ to $\pi/2$ minus the area from $\pi/2$ to $\pi$, but it is obviously not the area we want to get. How about $g(x)=-1$? Should the area between $y=g(x)$ and $y=0$ be negative, just because $g(x)$ is negative? No. We hope that the area from $\pi/2$ to $\pi$ appears to be nonnegative, and conserves the quantity. so we introduce absolute value function. In general, the area between curve $y=f(x)$, $y=0$, $x=a$, and $x=b$ is
$$
\int_a^b |f(x)|dx.
$$

Comment: an area can be nulle ! And $\int_0^\pi\cos(x)=0$ and it make sense.

Comment: The integral of $\cos x$ is $\sin x$

Comment: I don not understand what $|\cos x|$ means as opposed to $\cos x$

Comment: @dagda1 I added some description.

Comment: @Surb Yes, an area "can" be null, but not necessary.

Comment: @dagda1, it most certainly is not. $\sin x$ is the *antiderivative* of $\cos x$; it is not the "integral".

Comment: @Pockets I am totally confused, in my formula sheet, it states that the integral of cos x is sin x.  I do not understand how you are saying it is different

Comment: @dagda1, an *integral* is not an antiderivative; it is a very distinct concept; see [the Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral): "the definite integral $\int_a^b f(x)\,\text{d}x$
is defined informally as the signed area of the region in the $xy$-plane that is bounded by the graph of $f$, the $x$-axis and the vertical lines $x = a$ and $x = b$". (Also, I misspoke earlier: $\sin x$ is *an* antiderivative of $\cos x$, not *the* antiderivative.)

Comment: SO I should ignore the formula sheet?  What is the integral of cos x?  I still do not know.  Can I get a straight answer?

Answer (score 1):

Area of $y=cos(x)$ from 0 to $\pi$ is given below $\implies$

$\int_0^{\pi}cos{x}\;dx$

$=(\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}cos{x}\;dx)+(\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}cos{x}\;dx)$

$=[sin{x}]_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}+[sin{x}]_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}$

$=sin{\frac{\pi}{2}}-sin{0}+sin{\pi}-sin{\frac{\pi}{2}}$

$=1-0+0-1$

$=0$

If you take the sign convention then the area will be 0.But the magnitude of

that area is $1+1=2$.

Comment: why is it $\frac{\pi}2$ and not $\pi$. I'm missing that step.  I also don't understand why it is addition for the 2 ranges and not subtraction, like in normal integration or where the second range comes from.  I would love to know!

Comment: It is according to the graphical repesentation of cos x and sin x.When you are doing from 0 to pi you will not get that the value of sin x is 1 at pi/2.Above all  why the value of the integral is 0 you will not know if will do from 0 to pi.The value is 0 because in two interval two parts are symmetrical but opposite to each other by x axis